# Updating records based on the result of the same record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table where I have duplicate lines of the same Item_number.

I am wanting to do an update query where by I wish to update each line of the item_number based on the result of one of the item_number current records within the table.

My current query looks like this.

```
UPDATE RESOURCE
SET [resource code]='TOOL-G' 
WHERE [resource code]='FILLTOOL' AND OPERATION_DESCRIPTION='FILL MOULD TOOL' AND [set up]=2.5
```

This where clause will be the same for all of the queries as they are all based on that record currently in the system.

This however will only update 1 line of the 4 duplicate records for that item_number where by the query criteria matches.

What I am wanting to do is do update each individual row with different values apart from the one which matches the where clause in the query.

I.e The third duplicate record of a specific item_number has the information I wish to base my query on. However I want to update the first duplicate record in the list and so on.

I expect this will involve a sub query.

Hope my explanation is easy to understand. I am using Access 2007.

Comment: so basically you want to update column [resource code]='TOOL-G' if its duplicate?

Comment: Perhaps share your table layout and some sample data to help us understand better...